# scrapy - handling multiple types of items - multiple and related Django models and saving them to database in pipelines

Tags: python, django, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have the following Django models. I am not sure what is the best way to save these inter-related objects when scanned in spider to the database in Django using scrapy pipelines. Seems like scrapy pipeline was built to handle only one 'kind' of item

#### models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = CharField()


class ParentX(models.Model):
    field2 = CharField()
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, related_name = 'extra_properties')


class Child(models.Model):
    field3 = CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='childs')
```

#### items.py

```
# uses DjangoItem https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem

class ParentItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Parent

class ParentXItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = ParentX

class ChildItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Child
```

#### spiders.py

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["abc.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com",       # this page has ids of several Parent objects whose full details are in their individual pages

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        parent_object_ids = [] #list from scraping the ids of the parent objects

        for parent_id in parent_object_ids:
            url = "http://www.example.com/%s" % parent_id
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        p = ParentItem()
        px = ParentXItem()
        c = ChildItem()



        # populate p, px and c1, c2 with various data from the response.body

        yield p
        yield px
        yield c1
        yield c2 ... etc c3, c4
```

#### pipelines.py   -- not sure what to do here

```
class ScrapytestPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):


        # This is where typically storage to database happens
        # Now, I dont know whether the item is a ParentItem or ParentXItem or ChildItem

        # Ideally, I want to first create the Parent obj and then ParentX obj (and point p.extra_properties = px), and then child objects 
        # c1.parent = p, c2.parent = p

        # But I am not sure how to have pipeline do this in a sequential way from any order of items received
```

Comment: is `isintance(item, ParentItem)` helpful?

Comment: @dowjones123 did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do-it in a sequential way, i supouse if you store one item inside the other, an depakage-it in the pipeline, it might work.

I think is easier to relate the objects before saving in db.

In spiders.py when u " populate p, px and c1, c2 with various data from the response.body" you can populate a "false" primary key constructed from the data of the object.

Then u can save the data and update-it in the model if is already scraped in only one pipeline:

```
class ItemPersistencePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
             item_model = item_to_model(item)
        except TypeError:
            return item   
        model, created = get_or_create(item_model)
        try:
            update_model(model, item_model)
        except Exception,e:
            return e
        return item
```

of course the methods:

```
def item_to_model(item):
    model_class = getattr(item, 'django_model')
    if not model_class:
        raise TypeError("Item is not a `DjangoItem` or is misconfigured")   
    return item.instance   

def get_or_create(model):
    model_class = type(model)
    created = False
    try:
        #We have no unique identifier at the moment
        #use the model.primary for now
        obj = model_class.objects.get(primary=model.primary)
    except model_class.DoesNotExist:
        created = True
        obj = model  # DjangoItem created a model for us.

    return (obj, created)

from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def update_model(destination, source, commit=True):
    pk = destination.pk

    source_dict = model_to_dict(source)
    for (key, value) in source_dict.items():
        setattr(destination, key, value)

    setattr(destination, 'pk', pk)

    if commit:
        destination.save()

    return destination
```

from:  [How to update DjangoItem in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663459/how-to-update-djangoitem-in-scrapy)

Also you should define the **Field "primary"** in the models of django to search if is already in the new item scraped

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = CharField()   
    #primary_key=True
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=80)
class ParentX(models.Model):
    field2 = CharField()
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, related_name = 'extra_properties')
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=80) 
class Child(models.Model):
    field3 = CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='childs')
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [eLRuLL pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637977/scrapy-handling-multiple-types-of-items-multiple-and-related-django-models-a#comment55054070_33637977), you can use `isinstance` to tell which item you are parsing each time.

However, if you do not want to find yourself ever parsing a child item in the pipeline before its parents, consider using a single scrapy item for a combination of parent, parentX and child.

You might want to use [nested items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253569/939364) to do that cleanly.

Then, on your pipeline, take care of upserting the corresponding separate items into the database.