# I want to add item class within an item class

Tags: python, scrapy

Final JSON will be :

```
            "address": ----,
            "state": ----,
            year: {
                "first": ----,
                "second": {
                    "basic": ----,
                    "Information": ----,
                    }
            },
```

I want to create my items.py like (just example):

```
class Item(scrapy.Item): 
  address = scrapy.Field()
  state = scrapy.Field()
  year = scrapy.Field(first), scrapy.Field(second)

class first(scrapy.Item):
  amounts = scrapy.Field()

class second(scrapy.Item):
  basic = scrapy.Field()
  information = scrapy.Field()
```

How to implement this , already checked this https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#extending-items

[how to implement nested item in scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184557/how-to-implement-nested-item-in-scrapy)

but there are no clue about this concept ... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Item(scrapy.Item): 
  address = scrapy.Field()
  state = scrapy.Field()
  year = scrapy.Field(serializer=dict)

class Year(scrapy.Item):
  first = scrapy.Field(serializer=dict)
  second = scrapy.Field(serializer=dict)

class first(scrapy.Item):
  amounts = scrapy.Field()

class second(scrapy.Item):
  basic = scrapy.Field()
  information = scrapy.Field()
```

This way you can do this:

```
>>> b = second(basic="hello", information="hello world")
>>> a = first(amounts=3)
>>> year = Year(first=a, second=b)
>>> year
{'first': {'amounts': 3},
 'second': {'basic': 'hello', 'information': 'hello world'}}
>>> item = Item(address='address value', state='state value', year=year)
>>> item
{'address': 'address value',
 'state': 'state value',
 'year': {'first': {'amounts': 3}, 'second': {'basic': 'hello', 'information': 'hello world'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item(scrapy.Item): 
  address = scrapy.Field()
  state = scrapy.Field()
  year = scrapy.Field(first), scrapy.Field(second)    #You dont need to do like this

class first(scrapy.Item):
  amounts = scrapy.Field()     #this work and below

class second(scrapy.Item):    #and yes this work, you can do it in spider level or pipelines, just make your desired data, and pas it to year variable as you want. it will accumulate that
  basic = scrapy.Field()
  information = scrapy.Field()
```

Let me give you example,

```
first = {'first': first}
second = {'basic': basic, 'info': info}

year = {'first': first, 'second': second}
```

Comment: Thanks @thundermind, at spider level, i am able to do it very easily, but i want to declare all json elements at item level, is there any concept for that ?

Comment: There are ItemLoaders`https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html` for that and you can also try pipelines`https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html`.